# How to create dynamically named JavaScript object properties?

Tags: javascript, jquery, properties

Here is what I have

```
<form>
  <input type="text" name="item1" class="grab" value="userInput" />
  <input type="text" name="somethingelse1" class="grab" value="differentUserInput" />
  ... (any number of inputs)
</form>
```

Using JQuery/Javascript I want to build an array of objects with name value pairs that looks like this:

```
output = [ {item1: userInput}, {somethingelse1: differentUserInput} ... etc.];
```

I have tried this with no success:

```
var output = new Array();
$('.grab').each( function(index) { 
    output.push({$(this).attr('name'): $(this).val()} );
});
```

I have tried several variations including experimenting with eval(), but to no avail.  If I remove the $(this).attr('name'), and give it a static name it works... so how can I create dynamically named objects?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The literal-object syntax cannot be used for non-literal keys.
To use a non-literal key with an object requires the `object[keyExpression]` notation, as below. (This is equivalent to `object.key` when `keyExpression = "key"`, but note the former case takes an *expression* as the key and the latter an identifier.)

```
var output = []
$('.grab').each(function(index) { 
    var obj = {}
    obj[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val()
    output.push(obj)
})
```

Happy coding.

---

Also, consider using [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/):

```
var output = $('.grab').map(function() { 
    var obj = {}
    obj[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val()
    return obj
})
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked.  Thanks for the quick reply and the good information.

Answer (score 0):

I took only the id of the form as a parameter of this function:

```
function form2JSON(form){
    var info_ser = $('#'+form).serialize();
    var data = info_ser.split('&');
    var output = {};
    $.each( data, function( i, l ){
        var data_input = l.split('=');
        output[data_input[0]] = data_input[1];
    });
   return output;
}
```

The result object is something like this  `Object { fieldname="value",  fieldname1="value1",  fieldname2="value3", ...}`